# Canonical/tautological 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, tangent-spaces

The definition of the tautological 1-form is the following:

Let $Q$ be a smooth manifold, the tautological 1-form is a 1- form on $T^{*}Q$, so a smooth map $M \rightarrow T^{*} Q$.

The definition is the following: 
A point $x \in T^{*}Q$ has projection $q= \pi(x) \in Q$ represents a linear 1-form 
\begin{align*}
\alpha: T_qQ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
Now $\lambda_{can}$ is defined as 
\begin{align*}
(\lambda_{can})_x(v) = \alpha(\pi_{*} v)    \ \ \ \ \ \  (*)
\end{align*}
where $\pi : T^{*}Q \rightarrow Q $ is the bundle projection and $\pi_{*}: T(T^{*}Q) \rightarrow TQ$ its differential.

Now what I don't understand:  On the left hand side of (*), $v$ should be in $T_xQ$ but on the right hand side, it should be in $T(T^{*}Q)$.

Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A $1$-form $\lambda$ on $T^*Q$ is a section of the cotangent bundle of $T^*Q$, so a map $\lambda:T^*Q\to T^*(T^*Q)$. So $\lambda$ has first to take a point $x\in T^*Q$ (with $\pi(x)=q$, which means that as a function you have $x:T_qQ\to\mathbb{R}$), then a tangent vector $v\in T_x(T^*Q)$. Thus

$${\lambda_{can}}_x(v)=x(\pi_*v)$$

makes sense since $\pi_{*,x}v$ is in $T_qQ$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!